# Why does a context component re-evaluate during NextJs page routing?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Given a basic NextJs application with a simple context component and a couple of pages

```
// AppContextWrapper.js

export function AppContextWrapper(props) {
  console.log('AppContextWrapper - component function executed');
  const appContextState = useState();
  
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContextState}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
}


// _app.js

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <AppContextWrapper>
      <Layout>
         <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </AppContextWrapper>
  );
}
```

I notice that navigating from one page to another triggers re-execution of the `AppContextWrapper` component function.

In a basic non-NextJs React app this does not occur.

```
// index.js

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppContextWrapper>
      <App />
    </AppContextWrapper>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// app.js

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/other'>Other</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/other'>
            <OtherPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/'>
            <HomePage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Presumably this occurs because in the NextJs app navigation causes reassignment of `Component` and `pageProps` in `_app.js` therefore causing re-execution of the `MyApp` component function.

I have several questions related to this.

Is re-execution of the context component function potentially a problem?

Is there somewhere in a NextJs application to install context components where this re-execution can be avoided?

Lastly, I've seen code that uses `useMemo` in a context function, like so...

```
// appContextWrapper.js

export function AppContextWrapper(props) {
  console.log('AppContextWrapper component function executed');
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({});

  const appContextState = useMemo(() => ({ appState, setAppState }), [appState, setAppState]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContextState}>{props.children}</AppContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I don't understand this approach, is it sound? My understanding is that `useMemo` should be used for memoizing props or computed values that don't change to prevent unnecessary re-execution of the component functions of child components. Using `useMemo` to hold values already managed by React via useState seems pointless and redundant.

Comment: _"NextJs app navigation causes reassignment of Component and pageProps in _app.js therefore causing re-execution of the MyApp component function"_ - that's correct, and it can't be avoided. It shouldn't be a problem, though - are you experiencing any issues caused by it?

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem you are describing is from not using shallow routing.

Nextjs docs state this:

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again, that includes getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, and getInitialProps.

> You'll receive the updated pathname and the query via the router object (added by useRouter or withRouter), without losing state.

https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

You can use shallow routing in Link by doing this:

```
<Link to='/other' shallow>Other</Link>
```

And in push likes this

```
push({pathname: "/other"},undefined,{shallow: true})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that helps much. Shallow routing only works within queries for the same page, not cross page navigation, and I don't want to lose all server side rendering either.

Comment: @Neutrino have you solved this issue? I am facing the same problem right now